guided transform causes lightroom to expand the image beyond the frame
I often photograph my wife's quilts on the floor in our bedroom and use guided transform in Lightroom to correct the distortion.  Sometimes when I do it makes the quilt nicely rectangular but makes the image so large that much of the quilt is lost.  Below are two screen shots, the first the original photo and the second the result of the guided transform.  The left and top borders are well outside the original photo.  Is there a way to see the whole quilt after the transform or to do the transform in a way to avoid this?  I try to have the quilt a smaller fraction of the original frame, but I am looking for the most even illumination I can find and run out of room to back up even with a wide angle lens.


It can be done in PS, but not in LR. In PS make the canvas much larger before performing the transform using the lens correction filter.
If you really want guided transform PSCC has it.

I have tried in PS using the Transform command but it is much more difficult.  Is there a command like the guided transform in LR that you give it four lines and it makes a rectangle?  I have PS and could do it that way.

I would use the lens correction filter custom settings in PS instead of transform; but PS creative cloud has guided transform like LR does. Edited answer with link.

Unfortunately, PS desktop does not have that option.  I tried just expanding the canvas and going back to LR and that didn't work, either.  The light around noon was even in a different part of the room, so I could be back a bit farther and the LR approach worked well.  Thanks.

If you have the current LR and PS (photography plan) you should have access to the current LRCC
